# htaccess rewriterule challenge

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm building a MVC based CMS.

I'm trying to route all the urls as followed:

- `site.com/admin/...` > `admin.php?url=...`
- `site.com/member/...` > `member.php?url=...`
- `site.com/...` > `index.php?url=...`

The first two are no problem

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /cms/public_html/

RewriteCond %{REQuEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ admin.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^member/(.*)$ member.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

But when I want to add the third, that's where I get stuck. I've tried

```
RewriteRule (.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This however 'disables' the first two rules.
Then I tried:

```
RewriteRule !^admin(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This works for the admin part, also the index is shown, however isn't the rest of the URL parsed in the ?url.

How can I get this to work?
I should also be able to add more site parts (such as `site.com/gallery/`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about another `RewriteCond`?

Note that you need to list the set of `RewriteCond` for each `RewriteRule` as they only apply once.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ admin.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^member/(.*)$ member.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin(/|$)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/member(/|$)
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Demo for the last set here: http://htaccess.mwl.be?share=e7bf5c48-3332-56c1-a83b-d828b3c043a4

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm... didn't know that you need to specify the RewriteCond either...